# SSH login failed after setting up password for Same ssh user

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I am working on EC2 client. I have setup user account and respected public/private key for SSH login. It was working fine. Today I had to install ftp so that I can upload files through filezilla. SO instead of creating new user for vsftpd I setup password for same user (user which I was using for SSH). Now I am able to access FTP using same credentials but my SSH login is failed. It throws me error as "Disconnected: No suppoerted authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)". Now I am not able to access my ec2 instance using SSH at all.

Answer (score 1):

Either there is a problem with your keys or some problem with the SSH configurations. Is there anything you did or the installation process did to your sshd_config file? If it does not work then you may want to create a new instance and attach the faulty machine's EBS volume to it. This will help you preserve your data.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with the public key here, in the first instance I would try to ssh using verbose output (ssh -vv user@server) with your key.  Hopefully the output will give some direction for debug.